# mod_rewrite and ending slash problems (Apache + PHP)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.2

I've been searching for quite some time but have not been able to find an exact same issue as I have.

I hope someone here can help me out as I am getting pretty frustrated about it now.

I am running Apache 2.2 with mod_rewrite together with a PHP project I am working on.

I have successfully enabled mod_rewrite for Apache, and I am using the below .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /minpt.net/htdocs
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ./?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ ./?page=$1 [L]
```

I have a link like:

```
http://localhost/myproject/?page=news
```

I want to be able to access this link using a pretty URL like:

```
http://localhost/myproject/news
```

Or...

```
http://localhost/myproject/news/
```

(Note the ending trail).

Using my current .htaccess file (see above), link nr 1 without ending trail works just as I want it to. But as soon as I try to access the URL using a ending trail, I get in to wrong relative directory and my CSS, images, etc gets all screwed up because it thinks I am in another working directory.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by using absolute links through your website instead of relative links.

Alternativelly, add the following tag to the head tag:

```
<base href="//example.com/myproject/">
```

This will use that url as a base for any relative url in your website. This overwrites the current url you are browsing. See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) for more information on that tag.